# Displaying File lines in separate rows and each word on separate column using UWP C# XAML

Tags: c#, arrays, uwp, itemscontrol

What should I do in order to display all file's lines on separate rows in XAML?

I have such code:

```
public async void ReadFile()
{

    var path = @"CPU.xls";
    var folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

    var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(path);
    var readFile = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);

    foreach (string line in readFile.OrderBy(line =>
    {
        int lineNo;
        var success = int.TryParse(line.Split(';')[4], out lineNo);
        if (success) return lineNo;
        return int.MaxValue;
    }))
    {

        string[] splitLines = line.Split(';');

        ObservableCollection<ItemsData> items = new ObservableCollection<ItemsData>();
        for (int index = 0; index < splitLines.Length; index++)
        {
            ItemsData dataitem = new ItemsData
            {
                value0 = splitLines[0],
                value1 = splitLines[1],
                value2 = splitLines[2],
                value3 = splitLines[3],
                value4 = splitLines[4],
            };
            items.Add(dataitem);
        }
        itemsControl.DataContext = items;

    }

}
```

Unfortunately, instead of getting each line on each new row, I get the same line five times.

I get something like:

```
John 24 IT
John 24 IT
John 24 IT
```

instead of getting:

```
John 24 IT
Mike 14 GB
Steve 22 RU
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're replacing your item at each occurrence of the loop.

First, create your collection outside of the loop:

```
var items = new ObservableCollection<ItemsData>();

foreach (string line in readFile...
```

Inside of the loop, remove the `for`, since you don't actually use it:

```
string[] splitLines = line.Split(';');

ItemsData dataitem = new ItemsData
{
    value0 = splitLines[0],
    value1 = splitLines[1],
    value2 = splitLines[2],
    value3 = splitLines[3],
    value4 = splitLines[4],
};
items.Add(dataitem);
```

Then, when you exit the `foreach` loop, set the DataContext:

```
itemsControl.DataContext = items;
```

The final code would look like:

```
public async void ReadFile()
{
    var path = @"CPU.xls";
    var folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

    var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(path);
    var readFile = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);

    var items = new ObservableCollection<ItemsData>();

    foreach (string line in readFile.OrderBy(line =>
    {
        int lineNo;
        var success = int.TryParse(line.Split(';')[4], out lineNo);
        if (success) return lineNo;
        return int.MaxValue;
    }))
    {
        string[] splitLines = line.Split(';');

        ItemsData dataitem = new ItemsData
        {
            value0 = splitLines[0],
            value1 = splitLines[1],
            value2 = splitLines[2],
            value3 = splitLines[3],
            value4 = splitLines[4],
        };
        items.Add(dataitem);
    }

    itemsControl.DataContext = items;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your explanation is very indetailed so I can understand what happens. And, of course, your solution works!. Thanks again!